# Laravel- view is not working

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and installed Laravel 5.3 on desktop/Laravel/test directory. I have created a test.blade.php file in resources/view directory. I have also created routes.php in app/Http directory and added following code:

```
Route::get('/', function(){
    return view('test');
});
```

When I enter command in terminal: php artisan serve and go to http://localhost:8000 url in browser, it shows default page of laravel after installation. Why it is not showing view I have created? I have also tried writing following code in routes.php:

```
Route::get('/', function(){
    echo "Test";
})
```

But still it doesn't work. Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/releases#laravel-5.3)

> By default, fresh Laravel 5.3 applications contain two HTTP route
>   files in a new top-level routes directory. The web and api route files
>   provide more explicit guidance in how to split the routes for your web
>   interface and your API.

The `routes.php` is moved to different folder in Laravel 5.3. Update `routes/web.php` file.

Answer (score 0):

From the Laravel Documentation 5.3 
The routes directory contains all of the route definitions for your application. By default, three route files are included with Laravel: web.php, api.php, and console.php.

The routes.php was there in previous version. But in laravel 5.3 the routes.php is moved to `routes/web.php` as Saumini Navaratnam said.